# Not able to mask test.example.com with a CNAME of live.example.com. Simple issue?

Tags: iis-7, cname-record

Windows 2008, IIS7 environment.

Have a site running on our Web Server where I'm trying to simplify the URL in the form of **http://test-machine-name.sub.example.com** to be **http://live.sub.example.com**.

I have created a CNAME of *live* for test-machine-name.sub.example.com in our DNS but I am unable to browse to it using that URL.

I would like people to be able to reach the server using the simpler live address.

The site bindings are for the **test.sub.example.com** and all available ip addresses of the web server. If I can get this to work internally, then I can do the same for the external ip address. I feel like this is a very simple configuration but I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add http://live.sub.domain.com to the site bindings?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add live.sub.example.com to the site bindings.